# Linear model to account for confounding factors in dataset by using keywords

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

I have a dataset of home listings, in R. Here is a sample:

```
City      Price      Term    Size    Bedrooms     Bathrooms    Description

Appleton  3400       12      1150    1            2            Good location
Appleton  3780       12      1600    7            2            Nice area; 
Barstow   1400       6       900     3            2            Shady st
Raleigh   3700       12      1400    1            1            Quiet st, *veranda*
Ames      2200       12      1300    3            2            Good location
Ames      3400       12      1150    1            2            Good location, *veranda*
```

What I would like to do is ascertain which cities have the highest premiums and discounts for verandas. Certainly one way to do this would be to build two datasets: get cities WITHOUT verandas (i.e regular listings), and get cities WITH verandas. I could then get the mean rent per city using aggregate, and calculate the difference in mean between the two datasets.

But, I think there is a better way. The above approach does not take into consideration confounding factors like Size, Bedrooms, Bathrooms, etc. How might I take a multiple regression approach which would look at the impact of "veranda-ness" while controlling for other factors? I still want to answer the question of which cities have highest premiums/discounts, only using a more quantitative, robust approach.

I'm familiar with R's lm function and how to run a regression, but not sure how to extrapolate that to answer the question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a feature HasVeranda representing whether or not the listing has a veranda. To answer the question of how verandas impact pricing across cities (the interaction of City and HasVeranda), perform a regression of Price on HasVeranda interacted with city, allowing the confounds (e.g. Size, BedRooms) as effects in the model. In R, the formula for the regression might look like:

```
Price ~ City*HasVeranda + Bedrooms + Bathrooms + Size
```

From here typical linear model inference can be carried out. Checking the coefficients & p-values of the City:HasVeranda interaction terms will suggest the per-city veranda effect size & associated significance (probability the effect is non-zero).

Comment: City*HasVeranda  - do you know how i would search for this?  Have already filtered data by using GREP

Comment: What do you mean "search for this"? If you mean how to create the feature, something like `my_data$HasVeranda <- grepl('veranda', my_data$Description)` may work.

Comment: `wash.listings.Recode<-mutate(wash.listings, 
    Check=ifelse(wash.listings$ListingDescription == grepl('Veranda', 
    wash.listings$ListingDescription, ignore.case=TRUE), 'Veranda','NonVeranda'))`

Comment: The above code is my attempt to re-class the data set based on the keyword "Veranda".  It's not working though!  NonVeranda is logged successfully, but not the first "if" part of the ifelse statement.

Comment: That's a question for StackOverflow since it only relates to programming. There's a couple odd qualities of that code that I can point out.

Comment: Hmm, ok.  anything jumping out in the code as wrong?